# python: print xml document

Tags: python, xml, string, printing

If I print xml document this way:

```
print(doc.toprettyxml(indent=' '*spaces, encoding='utf-8'))
```

I got this:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<element att=""/>\n'
```

How can I get away the **b'** prefix and **'** suffix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`decode`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
print(doc.toprettyxml(indent=' '*spaces, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```